# Redefine thesection only for toc and section

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, numbering, amsart

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{§\arabic{section}}
```

I added the section symbol before the section number but the change is made in places where I don't want to see it like for subsections or theorems.

How to restrict the effects to the following two cases only:

- in the table of contents for sections only,
- when the section title is displayed (i.e. when I call `\section`)

I use a custom class based on `amsart` which does not modify titles style.

Comment: What is your document class?

Comment: I use a custom class based on `amsart`

Comment: For the basic article class, you can do what you want easily   with `titlesec` and its companion package `titletoc`, but I don't know if it is compatible with your class.

Comment: What I am afraid of is altering default style using those packages.

Comment: You would have anyway to look at the code to check for the vertical spacing, the font size, &c., and reproduce all these characteristics in the titlesec code.

Comment: About the only other place \thesection is used is \sectionmark, and possibly \thesubsection and \@currentHref (hyperref).  In \@startsection it shows up as `\csname the#1\endcsname`, so not easy to search for.

Comment: Is the class publicly available? If not, it's hard for people to help you with more detail.

Comment: Just consider it is AMSart

Comment: @JohnKormylo plus any theorems etc. counting within section. I guess the easiest place to hack in standard classes would be `\@startsection`. Not sure about `amsart`.

Comment: Amsart also uses \thesection in \thesubsection, and \appendix, and possibly \newtheorem.  Frankly, it would be easier to modify \thesection and handle the cases where you want the old format separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if your class doesn't alter `amsart` too much, you can easily create what you want by redefining `\sectionname`.

If the space between `§` and the number isn't wanted use `\renewcommand*\sectionname{§\ignorespaces}` instead.

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\renewcommand*\sectionname{§}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\duckument
\end{document}
```

First page of output:

[image]